# Adding 24 hour cookie to popup makes it not show at all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

Hey my fellow Stacklans.

I have a popup for a website that works beautifully. Open's from the corner on onload. Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/zcp1sqk3/3/

Here's where I have my problem however. I need to add a cookie that make's it not show for 24 hours after a user first sees it. I tried the following:

```
    // if no cookie
    if (!$.cookie('alert')) {
        window.onload = function() {
          $('.sliderPopUp').toggleClass('open');
        };

        $('.closex').click(function() {
          $(".sliderPopUp").addClass("close");
          // set the cookie for 24 hours
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
          $.cookie('alert', true, { expires: date });
        }); 
        $('img').removeAttr('title');
    }
```

But all it does is make the popup not show at all. I can't seem to figure out why as even when clearing my cache it won't show for a first time...

Comment: I don't see anything in the fiddle. There's nothing to click on.

Comment: For some reason it's not updating. But you have to turn the JS settings to 'Dom Ready' instead of 'onload' then click run @Barmar

Comment: you could just remove the `window.onload` part, since that's what the `OnLoad` setting does automatically.

Comment: Did you physically check in your browser to see that the cookie died? (expired)

Comment: @Barmar I'm just adding my full code so everyone knows what I'm actually using code wise. I don't know if it affects my problem or not.

Comment: When during the loading process is the cookie check running? If it's in `window.onload`, then assigning to `window.onload` won't have any effect, because that event has already happened.

Comment: Also, do you have any other code that assigns to `window.onload`? They'll replace this, so only the last one has any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I found out that having a $(document).ready function that included a $.cookie in a script tag inside body while having cookie js load in the head BELOW jquery as intended resulted in $(document).ready beeing processed before the cookie plugin could finish loading.

I moved the cookie plugin load script in the body before the $(document).ready script and the cookie works :D